# API call from Node.js not returning array

Tags: arrays, node.js, string, api

For testing purposes I have the following .js:

```
    var request = require('request');
request('https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market=BTC-LTC', function (error, body, data) {
    console.log (data);
})
```

This gives me the following response:

```
{"success":true,"message":"","result":{"Bid":0.01697926,"Ask":0.01698700,"Last":0.01698700}}
```

Which is the data I needed.

But when I try to access parts of the array, it won't work:

```
    var request = require('request');
request('https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market=BTC-LTC', function (error, body, data) {
    console.log (data.result);
})
```

gives response:

```
undefined
```

Can someone make this work?
I suspect the answer is not an array, but a string.
(the answer to data.length is 92)

I don't NEED to use request, I just want to get to data.result.Ask as cleanly as possible...

Comment: try `data=JSON.parse(data)` before logging it.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is being returned as JSON which is a string format.  To use it as a Javascript object, you need to make sure it gets parsed from the string into a Javascript object.  You can either do that manually with `JSON.parse(data)` or if you pass the `json: true` option to `request()`, then `request()` will automatically parse a JSON response for you:

```
const request = require('request');

request({json: true, uri: 'https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market=BTC-LTC'}, function (error, body, data) {
    console.log(data.result);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

your API returning string not a JSON object,

You can simply confirm by alert(data) if its JSON it will alert "`[object object]`" then you can read it by data.result or data["result"]

But if its alert plain string like `{"success":true,"message":"" ...}` then you have to parse it first into JSON object then you can read like `JSON.parse(data).result`